# Add tooltip to specific column on Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Data Grid View like:

```
if (this.dgv.Rows.Count < 1)
                {
                    this.dgv.DataSource = null;
                    this.dgv.DataBindings.Clear();
                    if (this.dgv.Columns.Count == 0) this.dgv.ColumnCount = 15;
                    this.dgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;

                    this.dgv.Columns[4].Name = "Added By";
                    this.dgv.Columns[5].Name = "AddedByFullName";
                }
```

as you can see I have column 4 called `Added By`

```
 this.dgv.Columns[4].Name = "Added By";
```

and column 5 called  `AddedByFullName`

```
 this.dgv.Columns[5].Name = "AddedByFullName";
```

I want to know how can I use `AddedByFullName` column as a tooltip for `Added By` column then I will just remove `AddedByFullName` column , is that possible? Regards

Comment: They are right next to each other! How would a tooltip repeating text a few millimeters away be advantageous?

Comment: I want to remove AddedByFullName column and convert it to Tooltip of  Added By, I  will not leave AddedByFullName @Plutonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CellMouseEnter` event can be a posibility to achieve this but it also can be done with `CellFormatting` event as Microsoft [REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2249cf0a%28VS.90%29.aspx)

```
  private void dgJobNotes_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.ColumnIndex == this.dgJobNotes.Columns["Added By"].Index)
            && e.Value != null)
            {
   dgJobNotes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToolTipText = dgJobNotes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `CellMouseEnter` or `CellToolTipTextNeeded` event for the `DataGridView`. Hide the column you want to use as the source, then replace the control name in the sample to match your `DataGridView`.

```
private void dgv_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == dgv.Columns["Added By"].Index)
        && (e.RowIndex > -1))
    {
        dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToolTipText = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgv.Columns["AddedByFullName"].Index].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridViewColumn` class has a `ToolTipText` property.  If you set it on the column, you will get a tool tip for the column header.  If you want a tool tip to show up on every cell, you can implement a `CellFormatting` event handler, pull out the right cell (from the column) and set the cell's `ToolTipText` property.  Something like:

```
 private const int InterestingColumnNumber = 5;
 private const string InterestingColumnToolTipText = "This Space For Rent";

 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
 {
     var senderGridView = sender as DataGridView;
     if (senderGridView != null)
     {
         if (e.ColumnIndex == InterestingColumnNumber) 
         {
             var cell = senderGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[InterestingColumnNumber];
             cell.ToolTipText = InterestingColumnToolTipText;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `CellToolTipTextNeeded` event which is created specifically for setting tooltip text. You don't need to use use `CellFormatting` or `CellMouseEnter`. If you are going to show text of column 5 as tooltip of column 4, you can write:

```
private void g_CellToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 4 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.ToolTipText = $"{dataGridView1[5, e.RowIndex].Value}";
    }
}
```